# Is there a workaround for the 'You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items.' error?

Tags: list, alert

I have been trying to piece together a quick and dirty system to allow users to leave messages on each others sites where any user can leave a message, but they can only see messages they have left, but the site owner can see all their messages as they aer the list admin.
Odd requirement I know, but that's what they wanted.

All working fine, but users will probably want an alert when a message is added.
When I try and configure alerts on this list I get a 'You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items. ' error.

I can see why this wouldn't normally be an issue - why would you want an alert to only be able to see items that you yourself must have added? But in this case it would be handy!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this OOTB so you're going to have to look at something like.

- [A workflow when adding new items
  using SharePoint Designer.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-example-send-a-notification-message-HA010182908.aspx)
- An event receiver on the list
- A commercial solution such as (blatant plug - the first one is from my own company)

  - [Pentalogic Reminder](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/reminder/reminder-manual?p=commonscenarios/newandupdated/newandupdated.htm)
  - [Bamboo Alert Plus](http://www.bamboosolutions.com/)

Comment: Thanks for not just plugging your own product! The custom workflow is what I am looking at myself, looks like it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the workaround mentioned above - set it to Read all responses - but then I'd browse to the list and edit that page, then modify the web part that displays the list items and add an audience to that web part to only display it to the site admin (or whoever should be allowed to see it).

Obviously determined users could still see everything if they try, but that cuts off the most obvious route and will stop them from seeing each others responses.

Answer (score 1):

The Only workaround I was able to find is to the change the Setting from read their own responses to "Read all responses" in advanced setting of the SharePoint Survey. Anyone has a solution to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it for read only users? If it is so, you need to configure Permission Level for Read Only users. The steps are clearly described [here.](http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/05/read-only-users-unable-to-create-alerts.html)

http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/05/read-only-users-unable-to-create-alerts.html

Answer (score 0):

stumped me for like a week! use rss feed - they must subscribe using the rss link via outlook, after the admin ups their permissions (design should work - not full control) on the survey list (be sure it's just that particular survey).