# Not being able to set alerts on a list SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, error, alert

In a list of **SharePoint 2013** I receive an error when I try to set an alert.

The error message is the following:
[image]
On the the other list from the community, the setting of alerts are working.
Can you please help?

Comment: Click on technical details. It should give you a Correlation Id. By this Correlation Id find actual error from log.

Comment: I already done that, but I do not have the access to see the logs, and I'm not that advance to understand them. If you have any other suggestion..?

Comment: The list advanced setting are set to only show items that you created to you only. The ability to set up alerts due to this setting is prohibited for security reasons.

Comment: And what should I do..?

Answer (score 0):

This might possible duplicate of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120835/you-cannot-create-alerts-for-lists-for-which-users-can-only-read-their-own-items) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9420/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-you-cannot-create-alerts-for-lists-for-which-user)

Please have a look to this thread once.

Also I don't think there is a need for setting an Alert on the items as if the user has a RSS feed functionality to the list where they can only see items that they have created.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I've already read that post, and are not helpful for me, from the first post, I already tried something. I have to use the "Alert Me" feature, and my question is why on the other list from the community is working and on this is not..?